# Monodromy matrix shortcut

Tags: matrices, functions

I'm a programmer and musician, not a mathematician, so I'm hoping someone with more knowledge can help with a problem I'm facing.

I want to obtain the monodromy matrix of a system:

$$[C(N, 0)] = \prod_{i=N}^1 [A(i)] = 
\prod_{i=N}^1 \left[\begin{matrix}
-d(i)(1-c) & c \\
1 & 0 \\
 \end{matrix}\right] $$

Where $d(n)$ is one period of a longer periodic function. I then need to evaluate three conditions:

$$1-C_{11} - C_{22} + \text{det}[C(N,0)] \ge 0 \\
1 + C_{11}  + C_{22} + \text{det}[C(N, 0)] \ge 0 \\
|\text{det}[C(N,0)]| \le 1$$

To further clarify, here is my current implementation in Python:

```
# assume d is a list containing our function
period = len(d)
Cn0 = zeros((2, 2))
tmp = zeros((2, 2))

Cn0[0][0] = -d[0]*(1-c)
Cn0[0][1] = c
Cn0[1][0] = 1

for i in range(0, int(period)):
    tmp[0][0] = -d[i]*(1-c)
    tmp[0][1] = c
    tmp[1][0] = 1
    Cn0 = dot(Cn0, tmp)

d2 = Cn0[0][0]*Cn0[1][1] - Cn0[0][1]*Cn0[1][0]

cond1 = 1 - Cn0[0][0] - Cn0[1][1] + d2
cond2 = 1 + Cn0[0][0] + Cn0[1][1] + d2
print cond1, cond2, abs(d2)
```

This works as expected, but as the length of $d$ increase, the computation time increases. Is there a shortcut to determining the monodromy matrix or evaluating the necessary conditions, given the information here?

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: The Q is very relevant to my medical imaging research problem. Even more specifically: how to find the $d(i)=const$, that preserves the three quantities in the OP's conditions? Is there an averaging invariance transformation of $d$'s to a constant?... (there's obvious to a musician connection to vibrating string problems?)

Comment: The eigenvalues of the monodromy matrices are computationally hard, even for small matrices and $N$ from my experience. @Greg Surges What's the motivation for OQ?